# Provide mean pixel values to Caffe's python classify.py

Tags: pickle, caffe, pycaffe

I'd like to test a Caffe model with the Python wrapper:

```
python classify.py --model_del ./deploy.prototxt --pretrained_model ./mymodel.caffemodel input.png output
```

Is there a simple way to give `mean_pixel` values to the python wrapper? It seems to only support a `mean_file` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code makes use of `args.mean_file` variable to read a numpy format data to a variable `mean`. The easiest method will be to bring on a new parser argument named `args.mean_pixel` which has a single mean value, store it a `mean_pixel` variable, then create an array called `mean` which has the same dimensions as that of input data and copy the `mean_pixel` value to all the elements in the array. The rest of the code will function as normal.

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--mean_pixel",
    type=float,
    default=128.0,
    help="Enter the mean pixel value to be subtracted."
)
```

The above code segment will try to take a command line argument called `mean_pixel`.

Replace the code segment:

```
if args.mean_file:
    mean = np.load(args.mean_file)
```

with:

```
if args.mean_file:
    mean = np.load(args.mean_file)
elif args.mean_pixel:
    mean_pixel = args.mean_pixel
    mean = np.array([image_dims[0],image_dims[1],channels]) #where channels is the number of channels of the image
    mean.fill(mean_pixel)
```

This will make the code to pick the `mean_pixel` value passed on as an argument, if `mean_file` is not passed as an argument. The above code will create an array with the dimensions as that of the image and fill it with the `mean_pixel` value.

The rest of the code needn't be changed.